# Implementing WCF method that supports either string or object as a method parameter

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, soap

I have the following contract in a WCF-based web service:

```
public List<string> GetAllPossibleQueryEngineHostNames(Instance instance);
```

I call it from the client like so:

```
string instance = "value";
svc.GetAllPossibleQueryEngineHostNames(instance);
```

Note `instance` is a `String`, not an `Instance` object.  I get the exception:

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:instance. The InnerException message was 'Error in
>   line 1 position 152. Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text' 
>   with name '', namespace ''. '.  Please see InnerException for more
>   details.

I'm looking for a way to fix this problem *without* changing *any* client code, since we need to be able to support legacy clients connecting to this service.

Note, the `Instance` class on both client and server *does* have an implicit conversion operator:

```
public static implicit operator Instance(string value)
{
   // Converts string to an Instance
}
```

However, WCF doesn't seem to take this into account while deserializing.  Is there any way to control exactly how WCF will deserialize `Instance` instances, allowing it to be either a string or an `Instance` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working.  Here's my code, in case anyone is interested in the solution.  Basically, I created a new file called Legacy.cs with the following classes:

```
public class InstanceSerializer : XmlObjectSerializer
{
    const string localName = "instance";

    public override bool IsStartObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader)
    {
        return String.Equals(reader.LocalName, localName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override object ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, bool verifyObjectName)
    {
        string xml = reader.ReadOuterXml();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        string shortCode = doc.Descendants()
            .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "ShortCode")
            .Select(e => e.Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        string connStr = doc.Descendants()
            .Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "ConnectionString")
            .Select(e => e.Value)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        if (connStr != null || shortCode != null) // Instance passed as Instance object
        {
            return new Instance(shortCode, connStr);
        }

        // Instance passed as String
        Instance instance = ((XElement) doc.FirstNode).Value;
        return instance;
    }

    public override void WriteEndObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    public override void WriteObjectContent(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, object graph)
    {
    }

    public override void WriteStartObject(XmlDictionaryWriter writer, object graph)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement(localName);
    }
}

public class InstanceBehavior : DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
{
    public InstanceBehavior(OperationDescription operation) : base(operation) { }

    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, string name, string ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        return typeof(Instance) == type
            ? new InstanceSerializer()
            : base.CreateSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes);
    }

    public override XmlObjectSerializer CreateSerializer(Type type, XmlDictionaryString name, XmlDictionaryString ns, IList<Type> knownTypes)
    {
        return typeof(Instance) == type
            ? new InstanceSerializer()
            : base.CreateSerializer(type, name, ns, knownTypes);
    }
}

public class SupportStringInstanceAttribute : Attribute, IContractBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        ReplaceSerializerOperationBehavior(contractDescription);
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        ReplaceSerializerOperationBehavior(contractDescription);
    }

    public void Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }

    private static void ReplaceSerializerOperationBehavior(ContractDescription contract)
    {
        foreach (OperationDescription od in contract.Operations)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < od.Behaviors.Count; i++)
            {
                DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior dcsob = od.Behaviors[i] as DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior;
                if (dcsob != null)
                {
                    od.Behaviors[i] = new InstanceBehavior(od);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, I added the `[SupportStringInstance]` to the top of my service implementation (Either the interface or the class should do).

Note, this only supports *deserializing* the `Instance` object (whether it's passed in as a string or an object).  You'd have to implement `InstanceSerializer.WriteObjectContent` as well to support serialization, which luckily I don't need to do (at least yet).

Answer (score 2):

The standard DataContractSerializer is not going to automagically convert your string to the instance type.  You can't overload that method in WCF so I would suggest you just take the string as an argument then do your conversion fo the instance.

```
public List<string> GetAllPossibleQueryEngineHostNames(string instanceName)
{
    var instance = Instance(instanceName);
    // Do everything else
}
```

I would then think about either keeping it that way or adding another method that will actually take an instance argument.

The last option would be take in a byte[] as the argument and try to hand parse it to the type you need and do the inspection to decide if it is a string or a type.

Comment: Another option is to use Message Dispatcher and Message Formatter. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2007/03/07/message-flow-interception-points.aspx

Comment: Thanks.  However, I need to support both formats.  The type is being changed to allow for new features.